# which sqlite to install with visual studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, nuget

My ultimate goal here is to install the correct SQLite package in Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 7 SP 1 64 bit
The project is a WinForms app and I might try UWP apps
It seems the NuGet Ice Cream Store has a lot of flavors of SQLite

System.Data.SQLite 1.0.113.1
The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.
This package includes support for LINQ and Entity Framework 6.

System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.113.1
The official SQLite database engine for both x86 and x64 along with the ADO.NET provider.

sqlite 3.13.0
SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. This package contains native libraries for SQLite on Linux, macOS, and Windows (desktop and Universal Windows apps).

The Last option here seemed like the correct and logical choice then I looked at this SO Post

[SO LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217526/installing-sqlite-nuget-package-installs-the-package-but-the-reference-is-not-av)

After 3 days of reading and searching I have given up hence the confusion has won

While I stated my ultimate goal above can I also assume NuGet will put the SQLite package in the project Reference Folder
**The question is I want to have a self contained EXE project once packaged**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last one was last updated almost 4 years ago, so clearly not the right option. That was from before Microsoft embraced SQLite as it's recommended file-based database system. Microsoft used to provide its own SQL Server CE but presumably decided that there was no point trying to compete withy SQLite as it already did what .NET developers needed. Notice that the new options start with `System.Data`, which is generally reserved for Microsoft's own types.

As for the other two, if you check the dependencies for each you will see that the first has a dependency on the second. As the descriptions say, they are both the official SQLite database engine and ADO.NET provider but, unlike the Core package, the first adds support for LINQ and EF6. Do you want that support? That is what determines which package to add.

If you don't know which you need then you can just add the Core package for now and add the other later if you need it. Also be aware that NuGet packages are added on a per-project basis. Even within the same solution, projects can have different packages added. You should/will add just the packages needed for each project you create.

Comment: I have assumed ADO.NET was just for web page development and EF is for cross platform development NEED TO READ Yes Per Package understood I thought by using WinForms I was only dealing with Net Framwork and that Core was only for UWP projects Thanks for the reply Will Go with CORE Have you seen this or used it https://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Pack-your-NET-program-to-a-single-exe-file-with-PostSharp-Community I am a long way from making an EXE file